# flutter auto route generator error : [dynamic] is not a class

Tags: flutter, dart, auto-generate

when I am trying to generate the routes for my app using flutter pub run build_runner build

I'm getting an error and the generated class can't be generated
I only see [dynamic] is not a class in the generated class

Comment: this kind off error occurs when your $Router class has an existing error and you run your runner. thanks

Comment: Did you create the view/screen class? Had the error when I forgot to save it

Answer (score 6):

try to clean and rebuild it ,It worked for me.

> flutter packages pub run build_runner clean

then

> flutter packages pub run build_runner build

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route):

> Make sure you always Save your files before running the generator, if that doesn't work you can always try to clean and rebuild.

Then:

```
flutter packages pub run build_runner clean
```